# Не создаеться автоматический хук

Tags: typescript, redux-toolkit

собственно проблема - не создается автоматический хук.
технологии : ts/RTK Query

```
import {createApi, fetchBaseQuery} from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query";

export const coinQueryApi = createApi({
    reducerPath: 'coinQueryApi',
    baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: "https://api.coincap.io/v2" }),
    endpoints: (build) => ({
        getAllCoins: build.query({
            query: () => ({
                url: '/v2/assets/?limit=10'
            })
        })
    })
});

export const { useGetAllCoinsQuery } = coinQueryApi;
```

файл package.json

```
 {
  "name": "react_skills_assessment",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.7",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.18.59",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.32",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.14",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.28",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.9.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.17.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bootstrap": "^5.2.8"
  }
}
```

ошибка в phpStorm :

> TS2339: Property 'useGetAllCoinsQuery' does not exist on type 'Api<BaseQueryFn<string | FetchArgs, unknown, FetchBaseQueryError, {}, FetchBaseQueryMeta>, { getAllCoins: QueryDefinition<any, BaseQueryFn<...>, never, any, "coinQueryApi">; }, "coinQueryApi", never, unique symbol>'.

Comment: До создания дело не доходит. ТС ругается, что в типе `Api<BaseQuery...` переменной  coinQueryApi нет свойства(ключа) useGetAllCoinsQuery, которое вы пытаетесь достать десериализацией...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

такой импорт исправляет проблему:

```
 import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';
```